# Page not found on nextjs

Tags: javascript, npm, next.js

[image]So, i just created a next js application. And i havenot touched any code yet but when i run "npm run dev" it gives me address of "ready started server on [::]:3000, url: http://localhost:3000"
But when i try to run it it gives me error of page not found.
Its a fresh project no changes has been made and i tried deleting the node modules. Nothing is working i tried restarting my pc and checked if there is a any port issues everything is fine.

I just tried to run a project with "npm run dev"

Comment: Can you hare with us the code?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your server is functioning correctly based on the log you've shared. A 404 error is usually considered a client-side issue. Do you receive any error messages in your server console when encountering the 404 error?

You mentioned that your project is fresh. Was it cloned or copied as a folder? In either case, I highly recommend making a copy of the project (if it's cloned, re-clone it in a different location) and check if the issue persists in this new setup. This will help you rule out any mistakes made during your initial setup.

If both projects generate the same issue, you should consider the following steps:

1. If possible, test if the project runs on a different computer. This will confirm if the issue is local to your machine.
2. Make sure Node.js, npm, and Next.js are freshly installed and updated to avoid version conflicts.
3. Running `npm install` is imperative to ensure all dependencies are correctly installed.

My advice assumes that you haven't modified the code. If you have, you'll need to review the changes you've made.

Lastly, does your project require Docker? If so, it could be a port issue between your project and the container, meaning that the container might be delivering content on a different port.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but i setup my project with src/app dir and again i clean installed without src dir and only /app/ and it worked. But i am still not happy why did that happened. I tried the code to run on a different machine and it also showed the same error.

Comment: Hi again. Based on what you've described, it sounds a lot like a configuration error. It seems you have two different instances running. My suggestion is to check where you have package.json files within the project. Ideally, there should only be one if it's a single project. If there are multiple projects in the same folder, that's a different story. If you do find multiple package.json files, examine their content and locations carefully. The one in the location where the project worked is likely the correct one. Good luck!